# missing params in object - should be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have this:

```
EventSubscription.prototype.subscribe = function(name, fn, filters, callback) {

    logger.debug('event subscriber subscribe:',{name,fn,filters});

};
```

we are getting this in the logs:

```
debug: event subscriber subscribe: {"name":"NotifyStaffUponReferralCreate"}
```

I find this to be very strange, because even if I pass undefined arguments, I should be getting this:

```
debug: event subscriber subscribe: {"name":"NotifyStaffUponReferralCreate", fn: undefined, filters: undefined}
```

does anyone know why the undefined arguments wouldn't show up for object destructuring?

**I am on Node version v10.10.0**

I did a little experiment to see what happens:

```
const foo = undefined;
const bar = 1;

const fn = function(bar, foo) {
  console.log({foo,bar});
};

fn(bar);
fn(bar, foo);
```

and with that I get:

```
{ foo: undefined, bar: 1 }
{ foo: undefined, bar: 1 }
```

I don't know what is going on.

Comment: `logger.debug` - what library is this?

Comment: Have you checked your `logger` code? Is it the same as `console.log`?
Chances are that it "cleans up" the parameters before logging them...

Comment: Your `logger` seems to use `JSON.stringify` (which ignores function and `undefined` values) not `util.inspect` like the `console` does.

Comment: Assuming you are using Winston…it uses `util.format` to convert objects. So basically: `util.format('%j', {name,fn,filters}));`, which will not include undefined values.

Comment: Ah shiiit, I figured it was something like that, yeah winston is what we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I am using the Winston logging package for Node.js.